# Get the name of a parent resource when working with a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming

I have a comment controller that uses a form partial to add comments. Now this controller is nested under any parent resource that needs to have comments.

```
resource :post do
  resource :comments
end
resource :poll
  resource :comments
end
```

If I want to have a form partial that automatically configured for the proper resource how would I do it?

Right now I have to set up forms on the page of the nested resource like so:

<%= form_for [@post, @comment] do |f| %>
    
      <%= f.label :title %>
      
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
    
    
      <%= f.label :body %>
      
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
    
    
      <%= f.submit %>
    
<% end %>

I would like to have a partial that looks something like the above code but that I can just call `<%= render 'comments/form' %>`

Any ideas on the best way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by passing a local variable to the comments partial using the locals hash:

In your nested resource, lets say, post's view:

```
<%= render 'comments/form', :locals => {:resource => @post} %>
```

Your comments form :

```
<%= form_for [resource, @comment] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %> 
  <%= f.text_field :title %> <%= f.label :body %>  
  <%= f.text_area :body %> <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Also, I encourage you to go through this guide on [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) where the details are explained.

Comment: Awesome, short sweet and I'm not repeating code. I should have thought of passing a variable in.